# How to set error notifications in FuelPHP

Tags: php, error-handling, fuelphp

I have a problem when I want to publish my local development to production environment,
this problem is about error message handling. When I access my site using development environment errors can be shown, but errors should not show in production enviroment .

I have tried to configure this in `/fuel/app/config/config.php` by changing `errors=>false` and referenced to this document http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/configuration.html, but it still does not change when I'm testing by producing an error on my query of database.

also I'm tried to change error_reporting to 0 and display_errors to 0 in index.php, still not fix my problem...

```
error_reporting(0);//error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

How I can disabled error messages on production environment in FuelPHP?

Comment: Why do you think should `errors=>false` disable those? To which reference do you related there?

Comment: have you also tried setting `errors.throttle => 0`

Comment: @hakre I just test that hopefully disable Error handling because before i'm test with this still keep showing error message

`'errors'  => array(
  // Which errors should we show, but continue execution?
  'continue_on'  => array(),
  // How many errors should we show before we stop showing them? (prevents out-of-memory errors)
  'throttle'     => 10,
  // Should notices from Error::notice() be shown?
  'notices'      => false,`

Comment: @sean that is same result keep showing errors message..:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the OP uses the work "environment" while he means "server".

FuelPHP supports multiple environments, "development" being the default. And in development mode, all error messages are enabled. If you deploy your code to another server, but don't set the FuelPHP environment, your app will run in development mode on that server too.

So the solution here is to run FuelPHP is production mode on the production server. You do that by setting the environment variable FUEL_ENV. Easiest is in your virtualhost definition:

```
setEnv FUEL_ENV production
```

see http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/environments.html

Answer (score 0):

I think FuelPHP have auto Error Handling , I was testing by Development an error , that is showing Error with description of Error (class,line,ect), and I was Testing  by Producing an Error,and  that is show error but with exeptionist 500 and not showing details of Error.

and for make sure I'm adding this code on bootstrap.php

```
// Select "Display Error" each the Environment
if (Fuel::$env === Fuel::DEVELOPMENT) {
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
} else {
    ini_set('display_errors', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit if errors are shown by editing the `/fuel/app/bootstrap.php` file. There you will find this line of code:

```
Fuel::$env = (isset($_SERVER['FUEL_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['FUEL_ENV'] : Fuel::PRODUCTION);
```

Add this code after the code above:

```
if (Fuel::$env === Fuel::PRODUCTION) 
{
    //disable all errors from being shown in the production server
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
} 
else
{
    //all environments other than production should display errors
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}
```

**Note:**
Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any affect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed. Source: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Also, this might be important. I am using Apache configuration to determine what environment I am running in. This means I set a `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
SetEnv FUEL_ENV production
```

I am running FuelPHP 1.7